# curl will not redirect

Tags: php, curl

Please excuse the probable simplicity of the question but I am new to `curl` and therefore finding my feet. I have the following which is in a php page and when called meant to post *dept=xxx* to *mysite*

```
$ch = curl_init( );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://mysite/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "dept=".$departmentName);
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

I have 2 queries:

1) When called the screen goes blank and the user is not redirected.

2) If redirection is correct, am I right in thinking that the following will correctly receive the data posted:

```
if (isset($_POST["dept"]))
{
$deptName=$_POST["dept"];
}
```

Comment: A blank screen in PHP means _go look in your error log for more detail and turn up error reporting_. Always in development, show errors on screen.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`   I see an errant `;` in this fragment: `"dept=".$departmentName;);`

Comment: Good advice thanks - and well spotted with the ;  I have been looking at the log but there are no entries relating this.

Comment: Why are you using curl vs doing a redirect?

Comment: I have no preference but using Wordpress the page url + post data does not appear to work. Eg sitename/?dept=xxx

Answer (score 2):

Include this **`cURL`** paramter to your existing set.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Comment: This certainly does something but bizarrely it logs me out of my site and since you need to be logged in to view the required page ...